# Is there a website where collected library for programmers?

Tags: java

In my case i need libraries on Java, but it will be fine in other languages to. Also be nice that it contain some reviews and catalogs or something like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This site has hundreds of libraries reviewed, grouped by purpose. http://www.java-sources.net/

The home pages shows the best of the bunch but if you click a category, it shows more options.

Answer (score 2):

You van get all standard libraries from [maven repos](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/)

Comment: also no categorization, no links to library site, only jars

Comment: You didn't asked it initially, well to get the home page and review of particular lib I would still say google it and you will get many good info. there are some site which publish reviews but I would recommend you to dig it and rate the lib your self. the lib which are there with maven repo are all standard.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. And sorry for that I changed question. I will keep in mind all your hints.